# OpenGL in Java on Netbeans: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, opengl

I am on a Mac running Netbeans 6.9.
I downloaded and installed LWJGL using this tutorial down to the letter:
http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_NetBeans

I finished the installation and copied sample code to see if my system is working. I got a bug, and was not sure if it was because of faulty code or I was doing something wrong. So I shortened down the code to this little simple bit:

```
package javaopengl;

import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

//Testing

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean fullscreen = (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("-fullscreen"));

        try {
            Display.create();
            Display.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

But I still get the same error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: =
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: =
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am not sure what exactly is going on, Would you please tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Note: When i am looking at the text in the development environment, it does not show those red lines indicating there are any errors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with openGL on Java, but it appears it is not finding a class file. On step six of setting up LWJGL in Netbeans (from your link) I would double check you selected all of the right jar files ans that you remembered to add the library to your Libraries folder.

Comment: It seems like exception messages are missing from the stacktrace you posted – it could be helpful to know what class is missing.

Comment: How would i find out what class is missing? I triple checked all the classpaths, i am 100% sure they match up and are the correct files. I posted everything i have and know about this problem. Is there anything else i need to set up? could there be something stopping it from loading the files? Any suggestions on where to go to get help for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you typing (or what is netbeans running) to run this? Since the Mac filesystem is fairly case-agnostic unless you've specified otherwise, running java javaopengl.main will look for a file main.java, which is there (Main.java will be returned). But the class is Main, and you can get this exception from the difference. If this is being run from an ant script, I suggest making sure you have the correct capitalization (the class should be javaopengl.Main). A simple way to test this is to delete everything except the class definition and an empty `public static void main(String[] args) {}`

Alternatively, you could have something simpler, like your classpath out of whack. Missing the lwjgl jar would get you there, but if you followed the directions in that tutorial, that actually seems less likely. Still, you can test this.

```
package javaopengl;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("well, main works");
    Class checkjar = Class.forName("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display");
    System.out.println("My ClassLoader found: " + checkjar.getCanonicalName());
  }
}
```

Also, remove `import org.lwjgl.Sys;` from your shortened example. It doesn't appear to be needed, provided it isn't the source of your problems :).

Comment: I ran that, got the same error, realized i did not even see "well, main works" in the output. I stripped it to just:

    package javaopengl;
    
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("well, main works");
      }
    }

And now it gives me that error even if i delete the library from the directory. Something weird is going on.
P.S. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: if you have a directory with all of your jars, you can also try this: `for f in *; do jar -tf $f | grep Display; done` and make sure that the exact class is there (some libraries like to rename packages between versions just to screw with you) and make sure the appropriate jar is indeed in your classpath.

Comment: What about making an empty main(String[] args) version? That works? Because I find that slightly unusual. Note that loading with Class.forName() should have no import statements (just in case).

Comment: I'm starting a new project from scratch, making sure it works with just a System.out.println("This works"); then adding the libraries, ill keep you guys updated on what i am doing.

Comment: It does sound like netbeans is telling java to load the wrong .class file. Delete your .java file and your .class file, start over, and make sure you've got the correct capitalization. Even if they display correctly in Netbeans (perhaps you first named the class "main" and changed it to "Main"), I could see this causing you a bit of grief. Oh, and consider changing your debug statements to System.err.println (to avoid a race between System.out and System.err).

Comment: Alright, i did all of that, and tried the following code:

    package javaopengl;
    
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("well, main works");
        Class checkjar = Class.forName("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display");
        System.out.println("My ClassLoader found: " + checkjar.getCanonicalName());
      }
    }

And this is what i got:

Comment: run:
Well, main works
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5448/discussion-between-ccoakley-and-steven-rogers)

Comment: So it is saying it is not in my library path, how do i fix that?